# bootbox.confirm prevent it from being called when another dialog is present

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, dialog, bootbox

I have having an issue where if `#complete_sale_button` in code below is clicked twice really fast; there are 2 dialog boxes that show up.

I realize I could make a status variable `var isOpen = TRUE` and check before opening the dialog again; but I have a lot of these confirm dialogs and other bootbox dialogs such as alerts and prompts.

It would be nice if I could extend the bootbox functions to not allow for 2 dialogs. This keeps my code cleaner. Do you know where I can find docs on how to extend it;or example way to do it? (I looked at http://bootboxjs.com/documentation.html#bb-confirm-dialog-options)

Here is code now:

```
$("#complete_sale_button").click(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    bootbox.confirm('Are you sure you are done with sale?', function(result)
    {
        if(result)
        {
            window.location = 'http://localhost/sales/complete';
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `bootbox.hideAll()`.

```js
$("#complete_sale_button").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  bootbox.hideAll();
  bootbox.confirm('Are you sure you are done with sale?', function(result) {
    if (result) {
      window.location = 'http://localhost/sales/complete';
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootbox/4.1.0/bootbox.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<button id="complete_sale_button">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: As stated I didn't want to modify any of my dialogs; so I came up with a better way. If you could have a look at it and let me know if this is a good solution; that would be helpful. Otherwise I will just modify all code based on your example. My code works for all dialogs too without mods to each bootbox call

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I came up with that doesn't require any modifications to my original code. This seems to work pretty well; but want some feedback or edge cases I am missing.

```
$(document).on('show.bs.modal','.bootbox.modal', function (e) 
{
    var isShown = ($(".bootbox.modal").data('bs.modal') || {}).isShown;
    //If we have a dialog already don't open another one
    if (isShown)
    {
        //Cleanup the dialog(s) that was added to dom
        $('.bootbox.modal:not(:first)').remove();

        //Prevent double modal from showing up
        return e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: That's a solution too but adding just bootbox.hideAll(); doesn't required much change in your code.

Comment: I have about 40 - 50 of them so it would take some time to test all of them.

Comment: You can also check the body tag - it will have the class `modal-open` when a dialog is shown (which would also cover any normal Bootstrap dialogs you may add).